# Off-Canvas Menu Css

Tags: css, off-canvas-menu

I'm following https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_off-canvas.asp to create an off-canvas menu.

I was wondering how to change it opening from the left and pushing content towards the right and instead opening from the bottom and pushing content towards the top OR the reverse: opening from the top and pushing content towards the bottom? Basically, I am wondering how to use this example and make it horizontal?

Thanks! :)

Comment: What is it to look like? Still full height but thin? If so, what does pushing the other content mean as it won’t be full width?

Comment: It would have the menu come down from the top, rather than from the left. I managed to find a way to have the menu at the top from the example above but I think I'm missing something because it still opens to the left, rather from top down. If that makes sense.

Comment: If it comes from the top is it pushing anything down or is it coming over everything that is already there?

Comment: From the top pushing down.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand completely. Is it to be full width rather than full height, so it pushes everything down, or is it still thin but tall?